# How can I detect if a reddit post contains a image?

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I was just wondering how can I detect a reddit post contains a image.

For example:

```
if submission.has_image:
```

So is there anything in Praw that allows me detect images?

Comment: I don't have any experience with praw but based on this [documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html), you can check with `is_self` if the submission contains only text. So if this is false you know that is has to contain an image.

Comment: Check if `submission.domain` is a known domain for image i.e. `i.redd.it`, `i.imgur.com`, etc. Not a catch-all solution, but given that there are just a handful of very popular image hosting sites used in Reddit, I think it's worth trying out.

Answer (score 0):

Please note Reddit .json api returns an `preview` object in it.
You can check it to find if it has an image or not

```json
"preview": {"images": [{"source": {"url": "https://preview.redd.it/h2h6v8vbkqb61.png?auto=webp&amp;s=57b083b51d7abd838b36829dfdedf136e9cb4c83", "width": 1149, "height": 1194}
```

**Note: please provide more information like your code what are you using to scarpe are you using it in browser or server side etc**